# What do I feed my betta and rasbora heteromorphas?

Tags: fish, diet

I'm planning on putting 6 rasboras and 1 betta in a 10 gallon (38 liters) tank together. Can I feed them the same food? What should I feed them, and can the rasboras eat betta pellet food? Any fish food brand recommendations? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your fish a larger tank, ten gallon is way too small.

The two types of fish can eat the same type of food, they eat food that is high in protein so any brand of food for carnivore/omnivore fish will do.

We try to avoid suggesting one brand over an other here on our site, as it can be a source for conflict.

For your fish to thrive you need a tank that is 50+ liters. Remember to cycle the tank properly before you add any fish, you can use some of the filter material from your betta tank to kickstart your new tank.

Source: https://www.thesprucepets.com/harlequin-rasbora-1378462

Answer (score -1):

I would feed standard flake such as Tetra ( I hope "such as" is permitted). Even my greedy 5 # Koi come up to eat flake after that eat their green peas and Koi pellets.